# How to merge response in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: xslt, wso2-esb

I have created a proxy which has request as :

```
<body>
 <p:GetPersonDataOperation xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org">
  <!--1 or more occurrences-->
  <xs:ID xmlns:xs="http://tempuri.org">1</xs:ID>
  <xs:ID xmlns:xs="http://tempuri.org">2</xs:ID>
 </p:GetPersonDataOperation>
</body>
```

Now In the InSequence i have used iterator as:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="GetPersonDataOperationSeq">
   <iterate xmlns:xs="http://tempuri.org" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org" preservePayload="true" attachPath="//p:GetPersonData" expression="//p:GetPersonData/xs:ID" id="IteratorForPersonData">
      <target>
         <sequence>
            <property name="ID" expression="//xs:ID" scope="default" type="String"/>
            <filter xpath="count(//xs:ID)>0">
               <then>
                  <log level="custom">
                     <property name="sequence" value="with id"/>
                  </log>
                  <payloadFactory>
                     <format>
                        <p:GetPersonDataOperation>$1</p:GetPersonDataOperation>
                     </format>
                     <args>
                        <arg expression="get-property('ID')"/>
                     </args>
                  </payloadFactory>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint key="GetPersonDataEP"/>
                  </send>
               </then>
               <else/>
            </filter>
         </sequence>
      </target>
   </iterate>
</sequence>
```

When i hit my proxy with the above request i am able to get output but Not for Both ID's but for ID=2. I want to get both the response i.e. for ID=1 and ID=2. I know this can be done using XSLT Mediator But i don't have any knowledge of XSLT Transformation. How can i create a custom response by merging both the responses for ID=1 and 2 using xslt mediator.Can i solve this problem using Aggregate Mediator?
Need help in this badly.Thanks in advance

Comment: I had such a problem. I solved it so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443232/as-in-the-iterate-to-change-the-message-and-send-it-fully-wso2esb

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Aggregate mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Aggregate+Mediator) in the out sequence to merge responses from iterate mediator. Refer to [Aggregator EIP](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IntegrationPatterns/Aggregator) also.

You can use something like below in out sequence.

```
<outSequence>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="-1" max="-1" />
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org" expression="//p:GetPersonDataResponse">
               <log level="full" />
               <send />
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
</outSequence>
```

[This blog post](http://dakshithar.blogspot.com/2012/07/routing-and-service-chaining-with-wso2_23.html) has a similar example.

Comment: But the above expression is giving me read timeout expression